# Wordpress: Call to undefined function wp_embed_register_handler()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website that is still under development. I was working on this website till end of Feb, 2021 and hold all works due to COVID crises. Till that date, website was working. Now I have resumed my work and just looking into website. But now, website is throwing an error "**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_embed_register_handler()**"

I have also crossed the file "wp-includes/embed.php" file in which this function exists and function is already defined before calling it. You can see attached screenshot of whole error tracing.

[image]

I am not getting this error on all pages but almost every pages. I am not able to understand why I am getting this error even I have not touched anything on website from last 3-4 months. And it was working fine when I was working last.

Can someone please help on this? I am not very experienced in Wordpress but have intermediate knowledge.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the current wordpress version installed?

Comment: @ShaikhAejazAhmed It is 5.7.2. But I think when I was working it was 5.6. But I am not sure

Comment: Looks like wordpress is up to date, can you please confirm if theme & plugins are updated as well. might be the issue is because of theme or plugin code conflicts !
Deactivate all plugins & check, activate 2021 theme & check.
If issue still exist try to install wordpress manually, Repair the database.
which theme you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the issue is in the theme compatibility with the WordPress files. I suggest that you update the theme and the WordPress core files.

The second option is to disable the Wp-Embed ONLY if you don't need it.
use this code by placing it in function.php of your theme:

```
function disable_embeds_code_init() {

 // Remove the REST API endpoint.
 remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wp_oembed_register_route' );

 // Turn off oEmbed auto discovery.
 add_filter( 'embed_oembed_discover', '__return_false' );

 // Don't filter oEmbed results.
 remove_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', 'wp_filter_oembed_result', 10 );

 // Remove oEmbed discovery links.
 remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links' );

 // Remove oEmbed-specific JavaScript from the front-end and back-end.
 remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_host_js' );
 add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_embeds_tiny_mce_plugin' );

 // Remove all embeds rewrite rules.
 add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'disable_embeds_rewrites' );

 // Remove filter of the oEmbed result before any HTTP requests are made.
 remove_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', 'wp_filter_pre_oembed_result', 10 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'disable_embeds_code_init', 9999 );

function disable_embeds_tiny_mce_plugin($plugins) {
    return array_diff($plugins, array('wpembed'));
}

function disable_embeds_rewrites($rules) {
    foreach($rules as $rule => $rewrite) {
        if(false !== strpos($rewrite, 'embed=true')) {
            unset($rules[$rule]);
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I am using some videos URL from youtube or other sources on my website so can't disable it. Can you please share any other option to fix this issue?

Comment: I need to look into your website plugins list and the full URL so that I can help you with this.